# How to get application in AndroidUnitTest

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, androidx

In AndroidUnitTest I need Application to pass to the one of classes (Actually my network manager). How I can get running application?

I tried for

```
instrumentationapplication = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext as Application
```

But, I get cast error and it does not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use

```
val application = androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext() as MyApplication
```

make sure you have the androidx test library dependencies.